# How to find the base $n$ such that $2_{n}^{12_n}=2_{10}^{6_{10}}\cdot 5_{10}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

I have met the following problem:

> How to find the base $n$ such that $2_{n}^{12_n}=2_{\small10}^{6_{\small 10}}\cdot 5_{\small 10}$?

And until now, I have no idea of how to solve it. I could try the conversion with some bases but it would be tedious. Is there a general method?

Comment: Is that "$2$ (base $n$) to the power of $12$ (base $n$) = $2^6\cdot5$ (all in base 10)"? Since $2$ is the same in any base, this doesn't make sense, as $2^6\cdot5$ is not a power of $2$.

Comment: Yes. That is correct. But even if it's impossible, could you provide me a working example? I got curious with this problem.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure exactly what class of problems you are looking at, but the only general method I can think of is substituting a number $(\ldots d_2d_1d_0)_n$ with $d_0+nd_1+n^2d_2+\ldots$ and trying to solve the resulting equation for $n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $12_n=1\cdot n + 2=n+2$.  Hence $2_n^{12_n}=2^{n+2}$, a power of $2$.  By the [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic), there is only one way to factor this into primes in the integers, namely as the product of $n+2$ copies of the prime $2$.

The other side, however, has a factor of the prime $5$.  Hence the two sides cannot be equal.

If you instead tried to solve $2_n^{12_n}=2_{10}^{6_{10}}$, that would have unique solution $n=4$, because in this case $n+2=6$.